# CSS flag icon in the header

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am working on to have two little flag icons in the header as shown in this picture:

[image]

I believe the html part is OK, but I cannot get them where I want with CSS.

```
   <header>

        <div class="title">
           <h1>Fonyódi Ákos <span></span> pszichológus, relaxációtréner, szimbólumterapeuta</h1>
        </div>
        <img src="img/Az_elet_faja.jpg" width="640" height="250" alt="Az élet fája">
        <div id="lang">
        <a href="../index.html"><img src="img/HUN.png" alt="Kattintson ide a magyar változatért" width="25" height="25"></a>
        <a href="../angol/index.html"><img src="img/GB.png" alt="Please click here for the english version" width="25" height="25"></a>
        </div>

    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  font: 12px verdana;
  color: gold;
}
.lang {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Fonyódi Ákos <span></span> pszichológus, relaxációtréner, szimbólumterapeuta</h1>
  <div class="lang">
    <a href="../index.html">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" alt="Kattintson ide a magyar változatért" width="25" height="25" />
    </a>
    <a href="../angol/index.html">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" alt="Please click here for the english version" width="25" height="25" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/640x250" width="640" height="250" alt="Az élet fája" />
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my code and then make changes according to your need.

```
<div class="title" style="float:left;background:#F00;">
    <div style="float:left;">
          <h1>Fonyódi Ákos <span></span> pszichológus, relaxációtréner, szimbólumterapeuta</h1>
     </div>

     <div id="lang" style="float:left;">
        <a href="../index.html" ><img src="img/HUN.png" alt="Kattintson ide a magyar változatért" width="25" height="25"></a>
        <a href="../angol/index.html"><img src="img/GB.png" alt="Please click here for the english version" width="25" height="25"></a>
     </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

you have to use main image as background and then put h1 and both img pic in 2 div with float property so they can be in one line.

Sorry for using color but you can use background image..Let me know if you get any problem. Thank you

Comment: Use line-height to adjust the lang img icon according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the two divs floating, in order to display them side-by-side.

```
<div class="title">
<div id="lang">
```

Otherwise they will display one below another, as a `div` is a block element.

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this.

```css
#lang a{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
#lang a.hun{
    background: url(http://placehold.it/25x25) no-repeat;
}
#lang a.gb{
    background: url(http://placehold.it/25x25) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
  <header>

        <div class="title">
           <h1>Fonyódi Ákos <span></span> pszichológus, relaxációtréner, szimbólumterapeuta</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="lang">
        <a href="../index.html" class="hun"></a>
        <a href="../angol/index.html" class="gb"></a>
        </div>
    </header>
```